# Typescript: Cannot find module angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am working on angular 2 project with angular-cli (1.0.0-beta.10) and want to use this library (https://github.com/Glench/fuzzyset.js). When I try to import it, Typescript is not accepting it as a module I don’t really know why. It gives me `Cannot find module` error.

As a workaround I tried to declare it as module in my `system-config.ts` file

```
declare module "fuzzyset" {}
```

I am importing it in one of my component like this

```
import * as FuzzySet from 'fuzzyset';
```

and added to System Config:

```
System.config({
  paths: {
    // paths serve as alias
    'npm:': 'vendor/'
  },

  map: {
    'fuzzyset': 'npm:fuzzyset.js/index.js',
  },
  packages: cliSystemConfigPackages
});
```

But now it gives `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.`

To solve this error I changed the module declaration to this:

```
declare module "fuzzyset" {
    export function FuzzySet(options?:any): any;
}
```

This does work in a way that everything is compiled, but then I am getting error at runtime as follow:
[Browser console errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jdtbu.png)

Can anyone help me on this? 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to solve the issue. It had some module definition issues and Typescript was not identifying it as a module.  Modifying the definition in the library did work but that wasn't the right way. The end solution that worked without modifying the library was to add its definition in `typings.d.ts`. In case you want to see the code:

```
declare module "fuzzyset" {
     function FuzzySet(options?: FuzzySet.FuzzySetOptions) : any;
     namespace FuzzySet {
         interface FuzzySetOptions {
             arr?: any;
             useLevenshtein?: any;
             gramSizeLower?: any;
             gramSizeUpper?: any;
         }
     }
     export = FuzzySet;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use:

> in app.ts

```
import fuzzyset from 'fuzzyset' (app.ts)
```

> in config.ts

```
map: {
    'fuzzyset': 'npm:fuzzyset.js/lib/fuzzyset.js',
}
```

> class definition,

```
        export class App {

      a: any;  // fuzzyset
      printThis: array;
      name:string;
      constructor() {
        // start doing fuzzy stuff
        this.a = FuzzySet()  

        this.a.add("michael axiak");

        this.printThisVar = this.a.get("micael asiak");
        // end doing fuzzy stuff
        this.name = 'Angular2'
      }
    }
```

> in @component:

```
<p>{{printThisVar}}</p>
```

> Working Plnkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/N5X8eBQhoRQCaeu1qWKB?p=preview)

Refer [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) and [this](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/include-external-javascript-libraries-in-an-angular-2-typescript-project/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are you using Angular 2? Because it doesn't work for me it keeps giving me `Cannot find module`

Comment: yes.  Angular 2.1.0.  check config.js.  Uses angular/core npm, whose latest is 2.1.0 - refer [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/core).  Did you try removing that declare module and simply import FuzzySet from 'fuzzyset'.  I am afraid, if you are making it complicated than needed to import a simple javascript exported module.

Comment: If you are not using Systemjs and its config file config.js, as I had provided above, it will *definitely NOT* work.  The Systemjs is recommended in both Angular2 (since you have tags Angular2, you are using it, I know that and I didn't even try Angular1, just so we are clear).  SImilarly typescript also recommends it in their documentation.  Also from System config documentation - "System Config is Built to the format ES6-specified loader API from ES6 Specification Draft Rev 27, Section 15,".  If you are building something on your own, it is only repetitive unproductive work, just my 2 cents.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the code I provided before complaining.  All you have done above is wrap the FuzzySet inside another module, to make your declaration to work.  Because you didn't have a module, now you create one and drop FuzzySet into it.  If you want to overdo things, *well that I can't help, really*.